# Conditional SQL JOIN based on column contents

Tags: sql, join, conditional-statements

I have a table, **event_sessions** that contains a **session_submitted_by** ID and a **session_submitter_type**.  I need to JOIN session_submitted_by to one of two different tables, based on the contents of session_submitter_type.

I can't just do an LEFT OUTER JOIN on both tables and choose whichever returns content because both tables may contain an ID match.

Here is my improper SQL/pseudo-code that shows what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
   SELECT es.event_session_id,
          subu.first_name + ' ' + subu.last_name as submitted_by_name,
          subu.email as submitter_email
     FROM event_session es
CASE WHEN es.session_submitter_type = 'speaker'
     THEN
         LEFT OUTER JOIN speakers subu 
         ON subu.speaker_id = es.session_submitted_by                       
    ELSE
        LEFT OUTER JOIN users subu 
        ON subu.user_id = es.session_submitted_by                            
    END
```

Any suggestions how to code this without having to resort to a UNION?

Comment: Why not use UNION ALL? Do you have any records present in both tables?

Comment: Yes, I have session_submitted_by ID values that may occur in both speaker and user tables... but would not be the same person in both tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. I would do it like so:

```
SELECT es.event_session_id,
      coalesce(spk.first_name, usr.first_name) 
      + ' ' + coalesce(spk.last_name, usr.last_name) as submitted_by_name,
      coalesce(spk.email, usr.email) as submitter_email
 FROM event_session es
     LEFT OUTER JOIN speakers spk 
     ON es.session_submitter_type = 'speaker' and spk.speaker_id = es.session_submitted_by                       
     LEFT OUTER JOIN users usr 
     ON es.session_submitter_type <> 'speaker' and usr.user_id = es.session_submitted_by
```

You basically use two left outer joins, and one only one of them is ever going to be active for any given row of event_session.

Note: If session_submitter_type is nullable then you need to add a NULL check in the second join to maintain the semantics of your pseudo code.

Comment: enl8enmentnow, that worked perfectly for my purposes.  thank you very much.

Comment: Great, can you please select it as the answer?

Comment: Holy crap.  I've been wracking my brain over this for the last three days and you come along and show me how to do it in one fell swoop.  Upvoted.  Thanks, man.